# can't find the logical error in c# asp.net below

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, webforms, odbc

I wrote this code to get data from mysql database using odbc connection. Its giving no error but no output as well. Am not able to find what the matter is.

```
public partial class Members : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();
                // We are now connected. Now we can use OdbcCommand objects
                // to actually accomplish things.
                using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM abc", con))
                {
                    using (OdbcDataAdapter ad = new OdbcDataAdapter(com))
                    {
                        ad.Fill(table);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ei)
        {
            Label1.Text = ei.Message;
        }

        GridView1.DataSource=table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `GridView1` set to `AutoGenerateColumns`? Also, if you set a break point at `GridView1.DataSource=table;`, is `table` filled with anything?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Have you verified that there is data in `abc` and whether `table` has any content once your query has run?

Comment: gridview is set to autogenrate columns, table initially has no records but it should fill when the query is done. I want to diaplay the whole table which is returned from the query.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem maybe: why are you using Odbc objects in place of Mysql ones?

Comment: @Fash do you know how to **debug** an application? Set a breakpoint at the line I pointed on my first comment to see if `table` has any data or if it's empty.

Comment: @Andre I did set a break point but how can i see the content of the table?

Comment: @Fash Just put your mouse over it and expand the floating window that will be presented, or use the *Immediate Window* (I like it very much).

Comment: For future reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: @Andre am not getting anything in table.So i guess that it's a connection issue can you please tell me that is the code proper?

Comment: Why so many down votes? Don't look on the question as if you've asked it. I know it is not a question you would have asked. This guy has a problem and he wants us to help him.

Comment: @Fash Are you able to connect to your MySQL database using another application, such as a query editor? If so, try running **that same query** and tell me if you get any result.

Comment: @Andre I can connect and get output if i use those visual tools in webforms. But when i code to get the same thing i get nothing.

Comment: @Fash Sorry, what do you mean by "visual tools in webforms"?

Comment: i mean the designer in visual studio 2010 where i can drag and place gridview and then select option to connect and get data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.config do you have a  connectionString? Please check that.
If not you can add datasource from visual studio designer and it will ask to add connection string in one of the steps .At the end you can remove datasource from designer but still have connectionstring in web.config file .And in your code behind can you try this

string SQL_CONNECTION_STRING = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionTest"].ConnectionString;

where "SqlConnectionTest" is the name of connection string in web.config.

Comment: Please try closing the connection after you bind the grid.

Comment: Everything was fine.i got the solution You can check that below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I converted a vb project just by replacing the c# file with the vb ones to make it a c# project, and this created this whole mess.The code work perfectly fine when done on a new projects.